# Codecov: No coverage information found on head

Tags: github, codecov

My [Codecov](https://about.codecov.io) check passes, even though the coverage decreases in my PR. GitHub tells me that Codecov throws the error

```
No coverage information found on head
```

I have no idea what that means. Could someone explain that to me? How can I fix this issue?

The following is the content of my codecov.yml:

```yaml
# For documentation please see https://docs.codecov.com/docs/commit-status

coverage:
  status:
    patch: off
    project:
      default:
        target: auto  # base branch coverage is target
        threshold: 0% # percent deviation allowed from target branch coverage
        base: auto 
        flags: 
          - unit
        paths:        # Working with Go, that's why I got these paths
          - "pkg"
          - "cmd"
          - "apis"
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas? @User12547645